# Selenium with chromedriver doesn't start via cron

Tags: python, selenium, cron, selenium-chromedriver, centos7

Python script with Selenium and Chromedriver in **headless mode** on CentOS7 runs fine when called manually.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('no-sandbox')
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

When starting script with crontab however it throws this exception at line 4 (above). Full traceback at bottom.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522
```

Cron is setup with crontab -e

```
* * * * * cd /to/path && /to/path/.virtualenvs/selenium/bin/python /to/path/script.py -t arg1 arg2 > /to/path/log.txt 2>&1
```

This produced errors like chromedriver couldn't be found. I then added following to crontab -e. 
1) Use bash instead of sh, although starting python script manually from sh works fine
2) Specify path to chromedriver

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin/
```

I tried different suggestions found on the web like adding --no-sandbox options to chromedriver in my script. All didn't help. Please note that I am using chrome in headless mode, so I think I don't need this export DISPLAY=:0 stuff in cron, or Xvfb libs as it used to be.

Python 3.6.1
Selenium 3.4.3
Chromedriver 2.38.552522
google-chrome-stable 65.0.3325.181

Full traceback

```
Exception in thread <name>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/path/to/script.py", line 53, in start
    self.site_scrape(test_run)
  File "/path/to/script.py", line 65, in site
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "/home/<user>/.virtualenvs/selenium/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/<user>/.virtualenvs/selenium/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/<user>/.virtualenvs/selenium/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/<user>/.virtualenvs/selenium/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/<user>/.virtualenvs/selenium/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Linux 4.14.12-x86_64-linode92 x86_64)
```

Comment: Can you try specifying the user via `crontab -u` and make sure your chromedriver bin has proper executable permissions?

Comment: `crontab -u <user> -l` shows the correct cron entry. chromedriver has following permissions `-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 7872560 Mar  2 02:19 chromedriver`

Comment: Yeah, seems about right. My last suggestion is to try `2.37` and `2.38` chromedrivers, because both support your browser version.

Comment: Thanks. But has still same error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522`

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Boy this was bugging me for far too long. Issue was following missing PATH directories: /usr/bin, /usr/sbin in cron. Complete cron looks now like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
* * * * * cd /to/path && /to/path/.virtualenvs/selenium/bin/python /to/path/script.py -t arg1 arg2 > /to/path/log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Should be noted that since this overwrites the PATH variable, it can cause havoc elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the same issue... I ran `echo $PATH` on the shell and put the result in the PATH inside crontab and it solved the problem.

Comment: just want to add that this (obviously i guess, since the problem is not python or chromedriver related) also worked for ruby and the geckodriver. I found this answer so probably others would too, but maybe it's worth updating the tags?

Answer (score 6):

What helped for me were the following steps:

1. Add 'DISPLAY=:1' to my crontab
2. Set the correct shell in the crontab (I use 'zsh')
3. Source the environment variables since crontab does not do this by default
4. Use absolute path to the chromedriver

## TLDR

1. The required modifications to your crontab would be:

   ```
   SHELL=/bin/zsh
   05 * * * * export DISPLAY=:<displayNumber> && source /home/<username>/.zshrc && cd <absoluteExecutableDirectory> && ./<pythonFile> >> log.log 2>&1
   ```
2. Use the following line to initialize the selenium chrome driver:

   ```
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(<absoluteDriverPath>,...)
   ```

Replace everything within the angled brackets with their respective values.

## 1. Set display

To find out which display to add to your crontab, use:

```
    env | grep 'DISPLAY'
```

Then add this piece to your crontab command:

```
    export DISPLAY=:1
```

## 2. Set shell

- If you have a non-default shell*, then set the shell.
  Find out the location of your shell with one of the two commands

  ```
  which bash
  which zsh
  ```

  Then set the shell to the response of the previous command (in your crontab):

  ```
  SHELL=/bin/zsh
  ```

## 3. Source the environment variables

Add one of the following piece to your crontab command, depending on wether you use bash or zsh:

```
    source /home/<username>/.zshrc
    source /home/<username>/.bashrc
```

## 4. Use an absolute path for your chromedriver:

When initializing the driver use the following line where  points to the selenium chrome driver.

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(<absoluteDriverPath>,options=options)
```

## Other

```
    >> log.log 2>&1
```

Means that all output is written to a file (This allows for easier debugging the crontabs).

Comment: What executable are you pointing at here: `&& cd <absoluteExecutableDirectory> &&`? Thanks

Comment: great thanks to you, the DISPLAY variable saves my day

Comment: Checking with `env | grep 'DISPLAY'` let me realise that connecting via vnc changed my :0 to :1 You don't know how grateful I am for this!!

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.9:

It's on my main workstation, so I always have a logged in X session going.

my selenium invocation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
location = 'http://example.com'
driver.get(location)
```

what I put in crontab:

```
33 14 * * * DISPLAY=:0 lxterminal --working-directory=/home/user/Documents/ -e /home/user/bin/get.stats.by.zip.py > /home/user/gbzp.log 2>&1
```

lxterminal is a relatively simple terminal program that I tend to use for most terminal stuff, instead of, say gnome-terminal, installed with apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm late but i think my solution is going to help a lot of people.I have found the solution after trying for 1 1/2 hrs. The solution steps are:

1. Open Terminal and run the command:

> echo $DISPLAY

Let the output of this command is: :0

2. Open the crontab for editing:

> crontab -e

3. Inside the crontab, append these lines:

> ```
>      DISPLAY=:0 
>      ## If output of "echo $DISPLAY" is: ":1", then change the above line to: "DISPLAY=:1" (without quotes)
>
>
>      ## if running the python file every 2 minutes:
>
>      # If firefox is used for selenium automation:
>
>      */2 * * * * export PATH=$PATH:path_to_python_executable_folder:geckodriver_folder_path_for_firefox; python path_to_your_python_script.py
>
>      # If chrome is used for selenium automation:
>
>      */2 * * * * export PATH=$PATH:path_to_python_executable_folder:chromedriver_folder_path; python path_to_your_python_script.py
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help some one.
I tried many options, but nothing helps me.
My goal is to start headless chrome on linux server and download file by using chrome functionality, because the website won't gave me a link to file.
I need to start script periodically so I choose to use cron jobs.

With **--headles=old** option I could start chrome but not download file: from cron and from commad line window,
with **--headless=new** option I could download file from command line window but not from cron jobs.

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with python2.7

My setting for now:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
prefs = {"download.default_directory": "path to your directory"}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=options)
```

perhaps this line would works to: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`

Like usually are in linux, you should always look to who starts the scrip and who owners the files.
So I changed cron jobs from www-data like I usually do, to root user, and I got my results.

```
wrong: 0 10 * * * www-data {your scritp} 2>&1
write: 0 10 * * * root {your scritp} 2>&1
```

For those whom this doesn't help, I wish good luck for finding solution.